# MSSQL Stored Proc and .FromSql with EntityFrameWorkCore 2

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following method for calling a stored procedure;

```
    public IList<Trader> GetTradersWithinRadius(int category, decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
    {
        var sproc = "FindTradersWithinRadiusLatLong";
        var sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>()
        {
            new SqlParameter("@CATEGORY", category),
            new SqlParameter("@LAT", latitude),
            new SqlParameter("@LONG", longitude),
        };
        var parameters = sqlParams.ToArray<object>();

        var traders = this.Traders.FromSql($"{sproc} @CATEGORY, @LAT, @LONG", parameters).ToList();

        return traders;
    }
```

Now if I execute the stored procedure directly in SQL Management studio;

```
EXEC    @return_value = [FindTradersWithinRadiusLatLong]
        @LAT = 43.590000,
        @LONG = -111.120000,
        @CATEGORY = 1
```

[image: screenshot mssql]

I get a result. However when I call my above method I am getting an empty set being returned?

[image: visual studio screenshot]

The Trader class is;

```
public class Trader : AuditableEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }

    public List<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }

    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    public List<TraderCategory> Categories { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public List<TraderGallery> Gallery { get; set; }

    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    public TraderReviewStatistic ReviewStatistic { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any reason its not generating the list I get through MSSQL Manager?

Comment: What is the response when you try to call GetTradersWithinRadius? It is null? How are you calling it?

Comment: @AussieJoe No error, just an empty result set. I'll Screenshot the result

Comment: Have you inspected the SQL generated by entity framework? Can you inspect those parameter values, on the server/SQL side, using SQL Profiler? Also, is ".ToArray<object>()" necessary? It seems like you could avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in how your composing the query. At the very least, you're making it more difficult than it needs to be. `FromSql` can handle named parameters out of the box, simply by passing values (it uses relative position to determine which value is substituted for what). Long and short, try:

```
var traders = this.Traders.FromSql($"{sproc} @CATEGORY, @LAT, @LONG", category, latitude, longitude).ToList();
```

There's no need to create an explicit array of `SqlParameter`s.

Comment: Interestingly if I do this I get the error `Must declare the scalar variable "@CATEGORY".` must the params match the order in which they are listed in the stored procedure?